# Marionettejs render child region error when using browser go backward and go forward button

Tags: marionette

Below is my code to render child region:

```
regions: {
    header: '#header-region',
    nav: '#nav-region',
    content: '#content-region'
},
...
onRender: function () {
    console.log('on render dashboardLayout...');
    this.showChildView('nav', new Nav());
},
```

onRender is called after the layout view finished rendering. Then I try as suggested by the [official document](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.layoutview.html). The minor difference is the parent view is root view, and is rendered by calling render(), not by calling show(), so I put child view render code inside the onRender callback.

It is working correctly when refresh the browser, but generate

```
backbone.marionette.js:448 Uncaught Error: An "el" undefined must exist in DOM
```

error when using browser go back and the go forward button. I try to trace back but got lost during this process.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

I struggled for one day for this issue, then find a work around. I believe it not the intended way by Marionettejs framework.

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
require('backbone.stickit');
var $ = require('jquery');
var api = require('../../models/_api.js');
var appData = require('../../routes/_data.js');
var Nav = require('./nav/nav.layout.js');

var DashboardLayout = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },
    el: '#app-container',
    template: require('./dashboard.layout.html'),
    regions: {
        /* regions hash defined here will only work 1st time when invoke render(). 2nd time calling render(), region has is not connected to DOM 
        */
    },
    onBeforeRender: function () {
        var thisView = this; 
        api.company.getInfo()
            .then(function(result){
                console.log(result);
                if(result.code !== 2000) {
                    // not login, or can't find user
                    Backbone.history.navigate('/login', true);
                } else {
                    if(!result.company) {
                        // TODO: show model dialog
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                }
            });
    },
    onRender: function () {
        this.addRegion('nav', '#vs-nav-region');
        this.addRegion('header', '#vs-header-region');
        this.addRegion('content', '#vs-content-region');

        var ss = new Nav();
        var navRegion = this.getRegion('nav');

        navRegion.show( ss);
    }
});

module.exports = DashboardLayout;
```

This is my route code for triggering the layout view:

```
var Mn = require('backbone.marionette');
var RootLayout = require('../views/root/root.layout.js');
var LoginLayout = require('../views/login/login.layout.js');
var SignupLayout = require('../views/signup/signup.layout.js');
var DashboardLayout = require('../views/dashboard/dashboard.layout.js');
var Router = Mn.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'default',
        'login(/)': 'login',     // http://localhost:8080/#/login
        'signup(/)': 'signup',    // http://localhost:8080/#/signup
        'dashboard/sent(/)': 'sent',
        'dashboard(/)': 'sent'
    }, 
    initialize: function () {
        var initData = this.getOption('keyInOptions');
    },
    // below are route functions
    default: function () {

        if(!this.rl) {
            this.rl = new RootLayout();
        }
        this.rl.render();
    }, 
    login: function () {
        // if you new it every time the route is triggered,
        // multiple event binding will happen. Since the root
        // layout view is not managed by region manager, so
        // it is not properly destroyed. 
        if(!this.ll) {
            this.ll = new LoginLayout();
        }

        this.ll.render();

    },
    signup: function () {
        if(!this.sl) {
            this.sl = new SignupLayout();
        }
        this.sl.render();
    },
    sent: function () {
        if(!this.dl) {
            this.dl = new DashboardLayout();
        }
        this.dl.render(); // render by calling render() on layout view
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post code for views as well?  and code for function showChildView. Have you tried using show()

Comment: nikhil mehta, I tried showChildView, same result. I just posted the more code.

Comment: You are rendering the layout view by calling render function true, but where are to showing its el. I mean render will just compile template but it will not attach HTML to DOM. You need to do that manually.